# How to Specify Gem Dependency Version at Gem Install Time

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am working with a gem that has a dependency whose version must vary depending on which Ruby version is running when the gem is *installed*.  Specifically, the current version of the `nio4r` gem requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2, and the `async` gem that needs `nio4r` should ideally be able to run on any Ruby version >= 2.0.

I tried putting some code into the gemspec file to vary the version, but it seems that it is executed when the gem is *built*, not when it is *installed*.  In other words, the nio4r version is hardcoded into the gem based on whatever version of Ruby is used to build the gem. Here's the code I tried in the gemspec (`say` is an OS X command to speak a string and was very helpful in knowing what was happening and when; I would of course remove it later).

```
# Recent versions of nio4r require a Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
# If the version used is earlier, load an earlier version of nio4r.
if Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('2.2.2')
    `say Installing latest version of nio4r`
    spec.add_runtime_dependency "nio4r"
else
    `say Installing nio4r version 1.2.1`
    spec.add_runtime_dependency "nio4r", '1.2.1'
end
```

As I said, this was executed on gem `build` and not `install`.  I am aware that I can use `bundler` for this kind of thing and put the specification in the `Gemfile`, but as far as I can tell that file will not be used when the gem is `gem install`'ed.

How can I get the dependent's gem version to vary at gem install time?

I'm looking for a solution that is automated, that is, does not involve any intervention by the user of this gem. Also, this gem will be installed as a result of installing another gem, so I don't want the user to have to keep up with changes to its dependent gem and have to modify the Gemfile manually. It would kind of be a violation of the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way that I know of to dynamically update the ruby version in the gem's `gemspec` file, however you can lock it to a specific ruby version:

```
spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.2.2'
```

Alternatively you could suggest to consumers of your gem (in the README perhaps) that they must force a specific version of `nio4r` if they are using versions of ruby older that 2.2.2.

In Gemfile for a new Ruby:

```
ruby "2.4.1"
gem "keiths_gem"
```

In a Gemfile with an old version of Ruby:

```
ruby "2.1.0"
gem "keiths_gem"
gem "nio4r", '1.2.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that is automated, that is, does not involve any intervention by the user of this gem. Also, this gem will be installed as a result of installing another gem, so I don't want the user to have to keep up with changes to its dependent gem and have to modify the Gemfile manually.  It would kind of be a violation of the Law of Demeter. I should have mentioned that, I'll do that now.